# It is possible to build a P2P system to trade Bitcoins?

Tags: alternatives, trading, trade

It is possible to build a peer-to-peer (similar to BitTorrent) system to trade Bitcoins?

Well, the discussion pointed in the 1st answer is very similar to what I have in mind. But, I have some sub-questions:

1. Is there any possibility to **use blockchains** transactions system to **have some "cash** on demand" to **use in trades transactions**(maybe with some taxs like fee transactions)? And **blockchains can carry more information** about what is going on inside this or others sub-systems?
2. The idea here behind the word "*trade*" is some system, that allows you to **trade your bitcoins for any other currencys or other virtual currencys** in ***any connected market*** around the world, by simple configuring a new "*node*" for that market.
3. ok. More obvius question. How? (*1 for me looks like a good idea*.)

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer to this question is currently unknown.  There's currently an [ongoing discussion](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=62879) about it on the [bitcointalk forums](https://bitcointalk.org/).

I'll update this answer if anything comes of it.

Comment: well, discussion looks far away from a real solution..

Comment: Indeed it does.

Answer (score 0):

My speculative answer here is that it should be possible for currency trading between two crypto currencies to be done safely in a distributed/anonymous fashion. (use new blockchain to track open orders, season with [crypto](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Contracts#Example_5%3a_Trading_across_chains) to taste.)

Truly decentralized trading against FX currencies is a lot less plausible.

Comment: how the system is supposed to hold/lock bets? I guess this is the final frontier...